# How to check if a currently running process is opened by root or user

Tags: bash, shell-script, process

I'm currently creating a BASH script to kill off processes. I first check if the process is running then kill it. But I would like to add a nested `if` to find out if that process was opened by root (not to the current script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ps -o ruser=` or `ps -o uid=`:

```
$ ps -p 930 -o ruser=
root
$ ps -C cron -o ruser=
root
$ [[ $(ps -C cron -o uid=) -eq 0 ]]; echo $?
0
```

-p matches by pid and -C by command name. OS X's ps doesn't support -C, but you can use pgrep:

```
$ ps -p $(pgrep -x cron) -o ruser=
root
```